# Getting a dictionary of all named arguments passed to a method

Tags: python

I have multiple methods that all build a bash command run in `subprocess`. They are all different but share a same basic logic. All the boolean keywords must be turned into `--myBool` if `True`, all the strings must turn into `--myStr=content_of_myStr` if not empty or `None` etc. Other arguments with specific types (list, etc.) are processed individually in each method.

I want to keep some type hint for the user (basic and common keywords), while allowing the user to extend usage to other uncommon keywords (via `**kwargs`) and, above all, I want to keep default values for some keywords. If put all named arguments in `**kwargs`, I think I cannot fulfill those needs.

How can I automatically get a dictionary of all pairs `key: value` passed to a method (explicitly named in the signature plus those in `**kwargs`)? Of course, my request cannot support `*args` in the signature.

For example:

```
def my_func(a, b, c=3, **kwargs):
    print(_some_magic_function_)

my_func(a=1, b=2, d=4)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

One solution would be to do like this:

```
def my_func(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

my_func(a=1, b=2, d=4)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

but this way, I cannot deal with default values and there is no type hint for the user.

Comment: What's the _purpose_ of this? You could simply `print(dict(a=a, b=b, c=c, **kwargs))`, for example, but without knowing the _why_ it's hard to say whether that meets your needs.

Comment: ^ What Jon said. Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would like the solution to apply to all methods without hard-coding 'a', 'b', etc.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Isn't this a question of how to do `**kwargs` keyword expansion but still have type hints? Sure, you can build your own dict, but is there a way don't have to?

Comment: @tdelaney I don't know; that's why I'm asking the OP.

Comment: As an aside, an advantage to hard coding parameter names is that they are translated to relatively faster indexes in the local namespace as opposed to a dict lookup for each reference. If you really use the parameters as a dict, well then that cost is okay, but if its just for convenience of typing, its not particularly justified.

Comment: @tdelaney: I want to have in the dictionary all the material the method can work with (the arguments explicitly mentioned in the signature, those with a default value even though they were not specified in the function call and of course, those in **kwargs)

Comment: But that's still doesn't tell us _why_ - [edit] to show what you're going to _do_ with that dictionary, perhaps.

Comment: I'm not an expert on type hints, but I think that `**kwargs`, default values and type hints are fundamentally opposed. `**kwargs` are for parameters you don't want to define in advance, but you want to type hint them? Named keyword parameters are not the same as `**kwargs` as they are put directly into the function's local namespace and access by index instead of name. So once again, not a `kwargs` dict thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you are looking for is mostly solved by using `locals()` and this is likely a *good enough* solution for you.

**However**, `locals()` does not give you function arguments, rather it gives you local variables. In particular, there are situations where, even when called as the first instruction in a function, `locals()` gives *more*. For example:

```py
class A:
    def f(self, a=1):
        print(locals())
        print(f"Hello from {__class__}!")
        
A().f()
```

prints

```py
{'self': <__main__.A object at 0x000002266A0659C0>, 'a': 1, '__class__': <class '__main__.A'>}
Hello from <class '__main__.A'>!
```

even though you might have expected it to print

```py
{'self': <__main__.A object at 0x000002266A0659C0>, 'a': 1}
Hello from <class '__main__.A'>!
```

I'm not sure how many of these sneaky extra locals the compiler can insert, `__class__` is the only one I'm aware of, so it really depends on how robust you want to be.

Option 1: works if no sneaky `__class__` variables are inserted by the compiler (this happens if you use `__class__` or `super` anywhere in a method).

```py
print(locals())
```

Option 2: works as long as you don't overwrite a sneaky `__class__` variable with an argument.

```py
print({k: v for k, v in locals().items() if k != `__class__`})
```

Option 3: Looks like the most robust but also the most horrible.

```py
import inspect
sig_params = inspect.signature(A.f).parameters
print({k: v for k, v in locals().items() if k in sig_params}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, thanks to [mCoding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73158104/16283580), here is the code I used:

```
loc = locals()
loc.update(loc.pop('kwargs'))
```